# Git crashing without any reason

Tags: git

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu local server to 14.04. I don't know if it's related with upgrade or not, but things is there was no such problem before. The problem is,

[image]

Googled this problem, and found that, deleting this file will fix problem. Removed index.lock file. Got error:

```
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Tried to `git reset`. After reset, tried to add, commit and push. First try gone well. It pushed commit without any problem. But second try, again same problem.

Tried to remove repo and clone again. Tried to `chown -R root:root /var/www`, to `chmod -R 777 .git/` of project. I even reinstalled OS ubuntu 14.04 server. Now same error message again.

Any suggestions? What to do next?

Comment: Do you see anything else weird (unexplained crashes, strange error messages) going on on your machine? It sounds like RAM may be going bad and git just happens to be one of the few things that checks data integrity and notices corruption first. If you're unlucky, you may be having other data being corrupted silently. I'd start with testing RAM on your machine with memtest86 http://www.memtest.org/.

Comment: @ArtemB it's virtualbox machine. Also I recreated machine and reinstalled os

Comment: I'd check the host's RAM then, if it's under your control. Alternatively, if you have another physical machine, see if the issue reproducible there. If it is, then it's something wrong with software (git or your system setup). If the problem only happens on one physical machine, then it's likely to be hardware-related.

Comment: +1 because your question shows a lot of troubleshooting, and you re-installed your O/S for such a small issue.

Comment: @Jimbo it stopped my whole workflow and you think it's small issue? if small for you then great, help to resolve. But I think it's big incompatibility issue between ubuntu 14.04 and git current release

Comment: What git versions where you using before and after the ubuntu upgrade ? What git version runs on the "remote" server (the one you `push` to) ?

Comment: What version of git are you using?  `git --version`

Comment: Do you have any processes running in the background which can influence git? like a backup or a cronjob to update your repo. Also, some filesystems can cause problems, namely remote file systems, and last but not least: lack of disk space and/or memory

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the index file itself and then reset, like this:

```
$ cd <your repo>
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset
```

this should rebuilt your index.

Answer (score 2):

Check what process is running that locks the file:

```
sudo lsof /var/www/XXXXXXXXXXX/.git/index.lock
```

If no process is using the file, consider restarting the system, if that doesn't work remove the file. After that, do a back up of your work and run `git reset`. Verify the objects of the repository using `git fsck --full`.

Comment: After restart same issue. Removing file doesn't solve issue, getting error bad signature.

Comment: Please read my question fully. I already tried all of that, even cloning repo again doesn't help

Comment: @heron you sure tried `git reset` or `git fsck --full`? The content of your question doesn't tell.

Comment: not git fsck --full . What will it do? Every time I need to do git reset to solve this crash issue? sorry but it doesn't solve root of problem. If this happens even after repo cloning, then I think the root of problem located deep in git it self with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @heron the problem is not ubuntu, at least some thousands of angry mails would be send. `git fsck` will "Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database". I seriously doubt git is the culprit and more likely is the repository you are trying to clone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51061/discussion-between-heron-and-braiam)

Comment: Well I got issue again, seems it occurs in random time.

Answer (score 2):

In your repository run the following commands:

```
rm -rf .git/index
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

The curious thing about your problem is that your git repo is in a public-ish place /var/www in the sense that perhaps you've got other services enabled (eg. web served filesystem) that allow update of files in /var/www.  What I suggest is cloning the repo into something like /home/heron/private/git0 and then see if it behaves itself there.

Another thing you could do is create a filesystem originating from an filesystem file, mount it up and then try git.  This is interesting because it forces you to check over the filesystem options.

For example, I had weird issues with checking out the linux repo once, and this approach helped me figure out the problem (for linux, you need a case-sensitive filesystem mounted as files in linux kernel can be different by case alone).  Your issue may be different in character, but the experimental method shown here may be still valid.